# Pagebreak, newpage, vspace all not working after a Table

Tags: tables, page-breaking

I have a section of my document composed of two tables. The following section is a section composed of figures. Between the two sections I want a page break. I have tried `\pagebreak`, `\newpage`, `\vspace` and they all do not seem to do anything. All these commands have been used in other parts of the document just fine. I think it has something to do with the fact that my second table is so long that it is "bumped" to the next page.

Does anyone have any suggestions for fixes? Any help is appreciated. I am new to Latex so apologies if it is a silly question.

The code is here:

```
\section*{Tables}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Some table} % title of Table
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ C{2.5cm}} 
\textit{m} \\ [0.5ex] 
0 \\
1 \\ % inserting body of the table
2 \\ [1ex] 
\end{tabular} \label{table:nonlin} \end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Some Table 2} % title of Table
\centering % used for centering table
\begin{tabular}{ C{2.5cm} } 
\textit{m} \\ [0.5ex] 
0 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 3  \\ 4 \\ 5\\6 \\7 \\8 \\9 \\10 \\11 \\12 \\13 \\14 \\15 \\16 \\17 \\18 \\19 \\20\\ 
[1ex]
\end{tabular}
\label{table:inv_case1} 
\end{table}

\newpage %HERE IS WHERE I TRY NEWPAGE, VSPACE, PAGE BREAK. NOTHING WORKS

\section*{Figures}

\begin{figure}[H] % Example image
\caption{Some figure}
\label{fig:case1_mod}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try a `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` instead of `\newpage` since you are using a bunch of `floats` (figures and tables)

Comment: No, it was never solved.

Answer (score 10):

`\clearpage` will force a page break and flush any pending figures, as shown below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,float}
\newcolumntype{C}{p}

\begin{document}
\section*{Tables}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Some table} % title of Table
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ C{2.5cm}} 
\textit{m} \\ [0.5ex] 
0 \\
1 \\ % inserting body of the table
2 \\ [1ex] 
\end{tabular} \label{table:nonlin} \end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Some Table 2} % title of Table
\centering % used for centering table
\begin{tabular}{ C{2.5cm} } 
\textit{m} \\ [0.5ex] 
0 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 3  \\ 4 \\ 5\\6 \\7 \\8 \\9 \\10 \\11 \\12 \\13 \\14 \\15 \\16 \\17 \\18 \\19 \\20\\ 
[1ex]
\end{tabular}
\label{table:inv_case1} 
\end{table}

%\newpage %HERE IS WHERE I TRY NEWPAGE, VSPACE, PAGE BREAK. NOTHING WORKS
\clearpage

\section*{Figures}

\begin{figure}[H] % Example image
\caption{Some figure}
\label{fig:case1_mod}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

I swapped \pagebreak or \break or \newpage
which all did not work in overleaf

I swapped them for the command:
\clearpage 
which doesn't clear the page, it puts the 
text on a clear page.
That's what im using now.